# Splitting a column with str.split while retaining original column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm using pandas to manipulate a CSV file.  My data looks like this:

```
  Col1 |   Col2   |         Street             
 ------|----------|---------------------------- 
  abc  | 11092019 | abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr    
  def  | 11092019 | abc,def,ghi,jkl            
  ghi  | 11092019 | abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno        
  jkl  | 11092019 | abc,def,ghi                
  mno  | 11092019 | abc,def,ghi,jkl            
  pqr  | 11092019 | abc,def
```

I am splitting the Street column by comma and as in the example this can return different number of columns once split.

My searching has got me to this point where I have the following code

```
i = df.columns.get_loc('Street')
df2 = (df['Street'].str.split(',', expand=True).rename(columns=lambda x: f"Street{x+1}"))
pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :i], df2, df.iloc[:, i+1:]], axis=1)
```

This would yield the following result

```
  Col1 |   Col2   | Street1 | Street2 | Street3 | Street4 | Street5 | Street6   
 ------|----------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------
  abc  | 11092019 | abc     | def     | ghi     | jkl     | mno     | pqr       
  def  | 11092019 | abc     | def     | ghi     | jkl     |         |           
  ghi  | 11092019 | abc     | def     | ghi     | jkl     | mno     |           
  jkl  | 11092019 | abc     | def     | ghi     |         |         |           
  mno  | 11092019 | abc     | def     | ghi     | jkl     |         |           
  pqr  | 11092019 | abc     | def     |         |         |         |
```

This is so close to what I want but I want to retain the original split column so the column Street in this example.  I just can't figure out out to keep that original column in the output.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: just do another pd.concat of your output with df['Street']

Comment: try with `final=df.assign(**df.Street.str.split(',',expand=True).add_prefix('Street_'))`

Comment: I think your code would have just needed a small change like `pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :i+1], df2, df.iloc[:, i+1:]], axis=1)` (note the boundery of the first `.iloc`. But I think the solution of @anky_91 is more pythonic.

Comment: anky_91!!  thank you!  Wow that is so much more straight forward than what I managed to cobble together.  Do you mind me asking what the two asterisks are for before df.Street.str.split?

Comment: @DanGreen that is to assign the dataframe into the existing dataframe. refer [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)